# Create a table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I couldn't able to create a table in SQL. This is my code.
And it told me that it had been a mistake:

> permission denied for schema public LINE 1:
> ...a8da3e90-dbed-11ec-b5aa-513dc633b9bb*/ CREATE TABLE student ^

```
CREATE TABLE student 
(
   student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   nama VARCHAR(20),
   major VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Comment: You do not have permission to create table. When I google this: "permission denied for schema public" I get this as first result: "If you get a "permission denied" for public. complete_oncology , but a "relation does not exist" for oncology , that can only mean only one thing: you do not have USAGE permissions on the public schema. GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO your_user; Then you should be able to see the table."

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify it, it will create it in the public schema and you don't have permissions.

```
Create table schema.tableName
```

In your case change another schema

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.student ( student_id INT PRIMARY KEY, nama VARCHAR(20), major VARCHAR(20) );
```

Comment: Note that OP is using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating tables you're doing with a certain user (the one you've connected to the database). That user has permissions on what it can do in the Database/Schema.

So you can either create your own schema and create your table there or add permissions/roles to your user so that you can create the table in the public schema.
But probably safest to do it like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS new_database1;


CREATE TABLE new_database1.student 
    (
       student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
       nama VARCHAR(20),
       major VARCHAR(20)
    );
```